# VB.net Graphics.DrawString with DirectionRightToLeft mixes up my string

Tags: vb.net

here is a sample code that isolates my problem.im trying to draw a string from right to left.. if my string starts with numbers then has a comma with a letter it rearranges my string.. but if I write it without the format its fine.. open a new project and add this form to see for yourself.. thank you

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim myFont As Font = New Font("Zipper", 24, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim myBrush As Brush = Brushes.Black
        Dim line1 As String = "220516,5130.02,N,00046.34,W,213.8,T,218.0,M,0004.6,N"
        Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft)
        Me.Width = 1400
        e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, myFont, myBrush, 1300, 0, format)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, myFont, myBrush, 100, 50)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: RTL is for support of languages such as arabic, which run right to left instead of left to right. punctuation and numbers will not be treated as simply as you expect. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: RTL is definitely NOT the thing you are looking for then!

Comment: guess I will have to use MeasureString then offset it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Alignment property:

```
Dim format As New StringFormat
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
```

You are also not disposing your font object.  For that, a simple Using bracket works well:

```
Using myFont As Font = New Font("Zipper", 24, FontStyle.Bold)
  Dim myBrush As Brush = Brushes.Black
  Dim line1 As String = "220516,5130.02,N,00046.34,W,213.8,T,218.0,M,0004.6,N"
  Dim format As New StringFormat
  format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
  Me.Width = 1400
  e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, myFont, myBrush, 1300, 0, format)
  e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, myFont, myBrush, 100, 50)
End Using
```